# osmdroid how to load maps from SD in progamm?

Tags: android, osmdroid

I have some maps in zip, made by Mobile Atlas Creator. I've put them on my sd-card in /osmdroid directory. Could you possibly help me and write this lines of code to load this maps from this directory (for example with path to archive)? Later I will make a dialog in which user could make a choice what map is going to be load. But user shouldn't have an internet connection.

Thanks.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

mapview = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
mapview.setClickable(true);
mapview.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
mapview.setUseDataConnection(false);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a tile source. I'm assuming that you have chosen the default MAPNIK. You might want to add a map controller too.

```
private MapController   mMapController; // Add this

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

mapview = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK); // Add this
mapview.setClickable(true);
mapview.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
mapview.setUseDataConnection(false);
mMapController = mapView.getController();
mMapController.setZoom(13);
GeoPoint gPt = new GeoPoint(yourLat, yourLong);  
mMapController.setCenter(gPt);
}
```

.

Comment: Thanks! My tile source is MAPQUESTOSM, but it is quite similar. Now everything works.